# Unable to run test, entry point missing

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest, python-unittest

**Hi all.** Tell me please. Wrote tests in different .py files with pytest. One of them has an entry point and pycharm allows it to run, and it is executed. In another file, the code is almost identical, but there is no entry point, and it is impossible to run.

*test_* prefix on test files available. When creating a test runner, it gives an error. I am attaching the error and the code from the test runner.

Please tell me how to collect all test files into one test suite and have one entry point. And if it's possible to write a testrunner.py without using a unittest but using pytest, I would be very grateful for the help! **Thanks a lot!**

```
   usage: test_runner.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: test_runner.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: test_runner.py --help-commands
   or: test_runner.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied</code>

______________________________________________________________________________

import unittest
from setuptools import setup, find_packages


def my_test_suite():
    test_loader = unittest.TestLoader()
    test_suite = test_loader.discover('tests', pattern='test_*.py')
    return test_suite


if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup(name='qwerty',
          version='6.2',
          packages=find_packages(),
          test_suite="setup.my_test_suite",
          )
```

Comment: The error you are getting is a *usage* error, it seems you are using the command in the wrong way, could you add the shell command you are trying to run in the question?

Comment: if you want to run tests with pytest, you should just call `pytest`  without args and let it collect the tests and run them for you  [usage link](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/usage.html)

Comment: @CaioSalgado The error was overcome. Test runner search happens but also finds 0 items. The problem is that through the terminal, using the pytest command and the py file with test (like python pytest test_filename.py), it also finds 0 tests.

Comment: Please add the name of the files and the command you are typing in the prompt to better understand